# How do I run "pub cache repair" in VS code to fix "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"

Tags: java, flutter

I tried to compile an under development Flutter app this morning and it failed with "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException". There had not been any changes to the code which compiled and run the night before. I have had problems where FLUTTER gets corrupted so my first response is to reinstall FLUTTER. This time it still gave the same error so I replaced my C: drive with a very recently cloned SSD and tried again but it still failed.

I search the web and found that "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException" had been reported on GitHub and the fix was to run "pub cache repair". I tried running it in the VS terminal with the following message

'pub' is not recognized as an internal or external
command,
operable program or batch file.

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to fix this problem so if anyone is able to help me with the "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException" or how to run "pub cache repair" I would appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: `flutter pub cache repair` - but honestly i dont think how "cache repair" would help

Comment: The flutter pub cache repair might work but could you tell us where that error is coming from? Is it coming from a library or something?

Answer (score 0):

`flutter clean` will delete all your project related cache.
Your next build will take longer because Flutter will have to regenerate a lot of files, but it should fix your issue.